# Apache2.2.*で、SNIとServerAliasの併用時の動作について

Tags: apache, ssl

apache2.2系で何度か経験していますが、
ssl.confにSSL関連のVirtualHost設定を入れる際、
IP共通でSNIを利用するとして、

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443
```

と記載しておき、

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
ServerName aaa.aa
ServerAlias www.aaa.aa
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
ServerName bbb.bb
ServerAlias www.bbb.bb
...
</VirtualHost>
```

とした場合、

```
https://aaa.aa
https://www.aaa.aa
https://bbb.bb
```

は問題なくサイトが表示されます。
しかし、

```
https://www.bbb.bb
```

はbbb.bbではなく、
aaa.aaのサイトが表示されるかと思います。

思うに、SNIの場合、ServerAliasが動作しないのかと思いますが、
これはApache2.2の仕様でしょうか？
それとも何か別のオプションで解決するものでしょうか？

現状、回避策としては、
以下のように２つに分割しています。

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
ServerName bbb.bb
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
ServerName www.bbb.bb
...
</VirtualHost>
```

この書き方はスマートではないですよね。
SSL更新の際も同じ内容で２箇所書き換えが必要ですし。

Comment: CentOS 6 / httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos, CentOS 5 / httpd-2.2.3-92.el5.centos で試しましたが、ttps://www.bbb.bb/ で bbb.bb のサイトが表示されました。
OS や httpd のバージョンは何でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！複数環境で再現していましたが、現状で確認した環境ではCentOS6.5 httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centosですのでほとんど同じ環境ですね。あとは、一応、openssl-1.0.1eです。

Comment: VirtualHostを分割する方法で既に動作している環境で、ServerAliasに戻してテストしてみたのですが、今度はうまく動いていました。ちょっと混乱してきました。なにか別の要素が関係しているのか・・・。公開サーバーなのであまりテストできず、時間があるときに新規サーバーを立ち上げて試験してみようと思います。